# BOX COLLIDER Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

как добавить Box Collider объекту через скрипт?

Comment: AddComponent?..

Comment: Не знаю но у меня это не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-моему так

```
gameObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверил, все добавляется через код

Comment: Вот у меня автоспавн объектов и к ним надо добавить бокс коллайдер. Как это сделать?

Comment: GameObject n = Instantiate(bullet, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        n.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
Таким образом вы создаете объект, временно его помещаете в переменную n и добавлете ему колладер

Comment: Спасибо! Обязательно сейчас попробую

Comment: я реальный тормоз

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смотрите.

1. Когда вы создаёте объект его нужно к чему то присвоить, например GameObject b = .....
2. И менять нужно объект как раз тот к которому вы присвоили, т.е b. .....
   Таким образом созданный вами объект, он помещается в b и далее мы к нему обращаемся и что то ему даем или что то с ним делаем